# sizing the input only on xs screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am adding the class `input-lg` but I only want it on `xs` screens and not on `md lg` screens

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
```

is there a way to do that using bootstrap only.

*I think @media queries are the only solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Styles applied for smaller screens in bootstrap apply to their bigger screen counterparts unless explicitly mentioned. Ao, if you apply something for xs only, it will apply to sm, md and lg. To achieve what you want to, you need to apply style for xs, and separate style for sm, which can carryover to md and lg screensizes.

Comment: You failed to answer: how can you make input-lg only on xs screens? without making 2 seperate input tags